# SELECT * FROM Table Where ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve information from my database depending on the ID a user types into my URL.

For example: If USER A went to www.exampleurl.com/index.php?id=1 it would echo out the user's information which has an ID of 1. Same thing if the id was 2, 3, etc. Users are entering their information via a form in a different file called submit.php.

Here is my code to retrieve data depending on ID :

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];

        //Variables for connecting to your database.
        $hostname = "";
        $username = "";
        $dbname = "";
        $password = "";
        $usertable = "";

        //Connecting to your database
        $con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
        connect to database! Please try again later.");
        mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);

    echo "Hello, " . $result['name'];

 ?>
```

Any ideas on if my SELECT request is wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is my code for showing the data altogether in a table. This works fine.

```
 <?php
        //Variables for connecting to your database.
        $hostname = "";
        $username = "";
        $dbname = "";
        $password = "!";
        $usertable = "";

        //Connecting to your database
        $con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
        connect to database! Please try again later.");
        mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

        //Fetching from your database table.
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);

        echo "<table border=1>
        <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Age </th>

        </tr>";

        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['age'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Comment: This looks like it's for a test or example project so I won't harp on security, but what is the error you are encountering?

Comment: what is wrong with this?

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't retrieving the data based on the ID. Fixed thanks to Miquel.

Comment: please use PDO and parameter binding, good programmers of earth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**→ Try This:**

You should consider using PHP PDO as it is safer and a more object oriented approach:

```
$usertable = "";
$database  = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB_NAME', 'DB_USER_NAME', 'DB_USER_PASS' );

$statement = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM $usertable');
$statement->execute();

$count = $statement->rowCount();

if( $count > 0 ) {

     $R = $statement->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

     for( $x = 0; $x < count($R); $x++ ) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $R[ $x ]['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $R[ $x ]['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $R[ $x ]['age'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

     }

}
else { echo "Error!"; }
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use [mysql_fetch_assoc function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) for retrieve the results.

```
 $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query, $con));    
 echo "Hello, " . $result['name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be error checking your mysql_querys:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
if(!result)
    echo mysql_error();
```

You should also retrieve the results:

```
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll consider some secure features like

1. Check if `$_GET['id']` is set and if is `int`
2. Apply Mysql escape with `mysql_escape_string()` function